# FIltering data onChange with useQuery not working properly

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I'm creating a select and want to filter on my data with it. So i use "refetch" function provided by react-query once I got my state updating

it looks like my data not updating properly. It behaves like this :

- I click on "comedy" no data is send to the server
- Then I click on "Drama" and `"?genres=comedy"` is send to the server
- react render movies with "comedy" gender

```js
  const [shows, setShows] = useState([]);
  const [genres, setGenres] = useState([]);

  const [filterGenre, setFilterGenre] = useState("");
  const [filterText, setFilterText] = useState("");

  const fetchShow = () => {
    let data = api.search(filterGenre, filterText);
    return data;
  };

  const query = useQuery("show-page", fetchShow, {
    onSuccess: (data) => setShows(data.data.shows),
  });

  const queryGenre = useQuery("genres", api.genres, {
    onSuccess: (data) => setGenres(Object.keys(data.data.genres)),
  });

  const handleSelect = async (e) => {
    setFilterGenre(e.target.value);
    query.refetch();
  };

  const handleInput = async (e) => {
    setFilterText(e.target.value);
    query.refetch();
  };
```

return

```js
<>
      <>
        {query.isLoading && <Spinner />}

        {query.isSuccess && (
          <>
            <select name="genre" onChange={handleSelect}>
              <option value="">All</option>
              {genres.map((genre) => {
                return <option value={genre}>{genre}</option>;
              })}
            </select>

            <input type="text" onChange={handleInput} />

            <div className="container-show-page">
              {shows.map((show) => {
                return (
                  <div className="card-show-page">
                    <img src={show.poster} alt="" className="image-show-page" />
                  </div>
                );
              })}
            </div>
          </>
        )}
      </>
    </>
```

Answer (score 1):

The refetch function is for refetching with the same parameters, *not* with different parameters.

react-query is declarative, which means you define all dependencies in the `useQuery` call - there is usually no need to call `refetch` manually if an input changes.

What you want is to put all your dependencies to the query *into* the queryKey, because react-query will refetch automatically if the query key changes. It will also make sure you'll get cached data per user input, levering the cache if the user goes back to a search they already made. If you want to avoid hard loading states in between those key changes, use the `keepPreviousData` option.

Finally, you don't need to "copy" data into local state (from `onSuccess`). react-query is a state manager and returns `data` for you from the hook.

My version would look something like this:

```
  const [filterGenre, setFilterGenre] = useState("");
  const [filterText, setFilterText] = useState("");

  const { data: shows } = useQuery(
    ["show-page", filterGenre, filterText],
    () => api.search(filterGenre, filterText),
    {
        keepPreviousData: true
    }
  );

  const {data: genres } = useQuery(["genres"], api.genres);

  const handleSelect = (e) => {
    setFilterGenre(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleInput = (e) => {
    setFilterText(e.target.value);
  };
```

where you do the data transformation for e.g. the `Object.keys` transformation also depends, you can do it in the queryFn:

```
const {data: genres } = useQuery(
  ["genres"],
  async () => {
    const data = await api.genres()
    return Object.keys(data.data.genres)
  }
);
```

or e.g. with the `select` option:

```
const {data: genres } = useQuery(
  ["genres"],
  api.genres,
  {
    select: (data) => Object.keys(data.data.genres)
  }
);
```

the difference is mainly when / how often the transformation is executed and what is stored in the query cache. I've covered this extensively in my blog: https://tkdodo.eu/blog/react-query-data-transformations

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your solution but I'm struggling to access the "data:shows" in my jsx. I'm totally beginner with react query. I'm going to read your article and I may find the answer

Comment: react-query returns an object with a data property, which I was just renaming to stick to your current naming. You can also do: `const showsQuery = useQuery()` and then access data via `showsQuery.data`

Answer (score 0):

I've just found a solution. I'm not sure if it's the best way to do it but now it works as I want. I did:

```js
const { query, isSuccess, isError, refetch, isLoading } = useQuery("show-page", fetchShow, {
    onSuccess: (data) => setShows(data.data.shows),
  });
```

and removed "refetch" to handleOnChange and handleInput + add useEffect with dependancies

```js
  const handleSelect = async (e) => {
    setFilterGenre(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleInput = async (e) => {
    setFilterText(e.target.value);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    refetch();
  }, [filterText, filterGenre, refetch]);
```

Comment: please see my answer above - you're trying to re-create what react-query can give you out of the box in a rather complicated way :)

Answer (score 0):

React doesn’t guarantee that state will be set immediately when you use ‘setXxx()’ and you are assuming it already has been in ‘handleSelect()’.

I’d try refactoring to use ‘useEffect’ that runs the query when ‘filterGenre’ changes.